# force instantaneous matplotlib figure update

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, action, draw

I have a scatter plot in matplotlib, with a `onpick()` action on them, as in the MWE below.

Whenever a point is selected, I run a computation on that point, that takes about `30` seconds. I want to notify the user by drawing a red circle in the figure on the same point, as soon as the user clicks on it.

The following MWE works, but it draws the red circle only after the `30` seconds:

```
from numpy import take
from numpy.random import randn
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X, Y = randn(2, 10)
ax.scatter(X, Y, picker=True)
def onpick(event):
    ax.scatter(take(X, event.ind), take(Y, event.ind), s=40, facecolors='none', edgecolors='red')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    sleep(30)#here I have MyLongComputation() in my code

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to request a figure drawing action with immediate effect? In case it matters, I am invoking the file from Ipython in interactive mode.

Notice that my call to `fig.canvas.draw()` is not ignored by matplotlib, but only postponed to when `onpick()` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden main loop only gets run between times to update the plot, you need to start your long computation in a way that lets the GUI carry on working, this can be:

- in a separate thread, (see python thread module),
- as an external process, (see the subprocess module),
- on other cores using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html),
- as an external object, possibly on a remote server, using [pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/index.html), [mpi4py](http://pythonhosted.org/mpi4py/usrman/index.html), or [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) in non blocking mode, note that the server can be on the same machine.

then when it notifies it has finished display the results.  The good news is you can potentially queue the requests for the results so your user could click on several points, (each highlighted immediately), the go to lunch or possibly away for the weekend.

Note that sleep blocks in python.